# Prestashop: Delete user uploaded file via AJAX instead of reloading page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, prestashop

The default way a user uploaded image displays, shows a small black X that looks like this (to delete the image):

```
<a href="path/to/yourproduct?deletePicture=1" title="Delete" >
```

When the user clicks that button, the page 'reloads' and the users uploaded file is deleted.

I can't figure out where the code is that is deleting that file - so I figured maybe AJAX would be a better way to go about it. Plus, just in case the user had entered information on the page, they wouldn't have to reenter it.

I changed the little black X to this:

```
<a id="deletePictureTrigger" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Delete" >
```

I also added this in *product.js*:

```
$('#deletePictureTrigger').click(function(e){
    alert('now it deletes');
});
```

This works and an alert pops up.

What would be the best way for this to continue?

Would it be something like this? :

```
$('#deletePictureTrigger').click(function(e){
    alert('now it deletes');
        $.ajax({
            url: "path/to/product?deleteProduct=1",
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,             
            //enable for saving on 'add to cart'
            //async: true,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                alert ("Deleted");
                $('.customizationUploadBrowse').remove();
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert ("there was an error:"+errorThrown);
            // ***** THIS GETS AN ERROR ***** //
            }
        });

});
```

Where is the method deletePicture that is getting called when that page is requested?

I'd like to automate this so the ajax deletes it without reloading the page.

Comment: The 'error' you get is because you are passing to the call `data` that's not defined :). Row #6 of your code. In success you can add a message for the user, and remove the element from the dom

Comment: I removed the data element - from the AJAX call and added alerts to success and error - but it is still erroring out when the user clicks the X.

I can see it POST to the URL in firebug, but then the ajax call throws the error.

Comment: Which error? Can you allow us to see directly?

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data  :::: I believe this is because what's being returned is the whole webpage and not just a JSON success method.

Comment: Why you would like to use AJAX, when you upload an image without submitting it's added by AJAx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make some changes to my ajax call like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#deletePictureTrigger', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
     var data = new FormData();
     data.append('ajax', 1);
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.href+"?deletePicture=1",
            type: 'GET',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            //dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,             
            //enable for saving on 'add to cart'
            //async: true,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                $('#preview-img0').remove();
                $('#customImages').remove();

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                console.log( jqXHR);
                alert ("there was an error:"+errorThrown);
            }
        });

});
```